# InitializeComponent InvalidCastExeption

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, listbox, itemscontrol

In my app I'm having a `ListBox`  that I have already set it's `ItemTemplate`, and it's working just fine. But after facing some problems I decided to change the `ListBox` into an `ItemsControl`,
So I just changed the `ListBox` keyword with `ItemsControl`, (whitch I don't know if it's allowed). But when I run the app an `InvalidCastExeption` is unhandeled at the `InitializeComponent`.

I am still new to programming so can anyone help me with this?

EDIT:

```
<ListBox Name="ChannelsSearchResaultList" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Name="ChannelContainer" Margin="5" Width="470" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="BlueViolet" 
                BorderThickness="2" Background="#FF1D1D1D" MouseLeftButtonDown=
                "Border_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp=
                "ChannelContainer_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <Grid Height="110">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="340"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Logo}"  Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration}"  Margin="10,5" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="Bold" 
                            Foreground="Red"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Views}" Canvas.Top="60" 
                            Canvas.Left="20" />
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: post some code, you probably forgot to change the name in a Style.

Comment: We can help you if you show us what your error says, along with any inner `Exception` messages.

Comment: InvalidCastExcepion--> you can cast the object, maybe you are trying to cast ItemsControl to ListBox... I hope you understand.

Comment: if you post the code, some cute guy help you :)

Comment: OK, I have added some code, and this one is working but after I change the ListBox keyword into ItemsControl, it doesn't work

Comment: There is *no* problem when changing `ListBox` with `ItemsControl` in this code. This is *not* where your problem is. The error says invalid cast, so search your code for the word `(ListBox)` (including the brackets) and replace with `(ItemsControl)` (where appropriate).

Comment: Well, I thought of that at first, but there is no such thing as ListBox in my code. all I have related to the ListBox is the ItemSource, and according to my knowlage ListBox and ItemsControl ItemSource can be implemented with the same code.

Comment: Is there not an inner `Exception`? If not, can you show the stack trace please?

Comment: What is an inner exeption, I'm sorry I'm still a beginner.

Comment: It's working now!!
I tryed to retype the code of binding the ItemsContol source to the list of items, and it's working now!
Can anyone please explain to me how did it happen?

Comment: From MSDN: *In cases where an `Exception` is thrown as a direct result of a previous `Exception`, the `InnerException` property describes the original error. This information may allow you to handle the error more efficiently. If there is no original error, the value of `InnerException` will be a null reference.* To find it, click `View Detail` on the popup window that appears when you get an `Exception`... this opens a window with the `Exception` details - it shows both the stack trace *and* the inner `Exception` if there is one (among other things).

Comment: You probably just had a typing error.